# jquery .makeEditable selector

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

using datatables and jeditable plugins. Whenever I use this selector: .$('td[class!="readonly"]') I'm unable to do in-line edits. If I comment out the selector, then everything works great. I dont' want to edit the checkbox column for obivous reasons.

any help?

thanks!!

here's my init.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "js/DataTables-1.9.0/scripts/server_processing.php",
                "aoColumns": [
                            {"bVisible": false },//id                                                                                               
                            {},//code
                            {},//project
                            {},//task
                            {},//type
                            {},//description
                            {"fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                return "<input type='checkbox' class='readonly' value='" + oObj.aData[0] + "' name='check'>";
                                },
                            "sClass": "readonly",
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false
                            }//checkbox
                            ]

                })
                .$('td[class!="readonly"]')
                .makeEditable({
                    "sUpdateURL": "js/DataTables-1.9.0/scripts/server_editing.php"
            })
        } );
```

Here's my table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="2%">ID</th>                  
        <th width="10%">Code</th>
        <th width="10%">Project</th>
        <th width="10%">Task</th>
        <th width="10%">Type</th>
        <th width="50%">Description</th>
        <th width="2%">Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        <td class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        <td class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        <td class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        <td class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        <td class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        <td align="center" class="readonly">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>              
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Delete</th>   
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

**edit**

thanks for the syntax help everyone.

I changed it to this, but still no dice?? Again, removing the selector inline editing works.??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({options});
    $('td').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        if(self.hasClass("readonly") != true){
            self.makeEditable({"sUpdateURL": "js/DataTables-1.9.0/scripts/server_editing.php"})
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$().hasClass();`

You shouldn't string those together, a jquery element is not a method or property of another... I'm surprised it works with the selector removed too... try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
       "sAjaxSource": "js/DataTables-1.9.0/scripts/server_processing.php",
       "aoColumns": [
          {"bVisible": false},//id     
          {},//code
          {},//project
          {},//task
          {},//type
          {},//description
         {"fnRender": function (oObj) {
               return "<input type='checkbox' class='readonly' value='" + oObj.aData[0] + "' name='check'>";
         },
        "sClass": "readonly",
        "bSearchable": false,
        "bSortable": false
        }//checkbox
     ]

    });
    $('td').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        if(self.hasClass("readonly") != true){
            self.makeEditable({"sUpdateURL": "js/DataTables-1.9.0/scripts/server_editing.php"})
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: again, thanks for the syntax help; I could have accepted either of these answers. In the end, I never got the .$(selector) method to work. I'm not even sure this is possible with .makeEditable

Comment: I simply added aoColumns option to .makeEditable and set the 'readonly' column def to null

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution... and I'm not sure why @Juicy Scripter's solution didn't work, but I'm sure it was situational specific.

Answer (score 0):

You're using chaining in a wrong maner:

```
$('#example').dataTable(options)
  .find('td[class!="readonly"]')
  .makeEditable(options);

// Next code is probably lead to error due to fact that $ isn't exists
// in result of dataTable function, thus leading to makeEditable not run...
$('#example').dataTable(options)
  .$('td[class!="readonly"]')
  .makeEditable(options);
```

Comment: This is assuming the table is populated already with all fields.

Comment: @Relic, the issue is syntax error (there is no `$` property in the result of `dataTable` function) and thus code following `.$('td[class!="readonly"]')` is not run at all.

Comment: My answer says the same thing... I was commenting on your answer/his original code as a forward suggestion. We're in agreement about the syntax issue though.

Comment: @Relic, I just think you're taking it too far by suggesting usage of other code that doesn't show where the problem is and not really make it different from the original solution if the error is fixed...

Comment: @Relic, and as for population of data if the `dataTable` doing synchronous call to server it makes all the date populated before next code is run which make sense to me. I have no idea what `dataTable` is doing as long as it doesn't described here and without problematic part of script it's working...

Comment: sooo what you're saying is, I shouldn't inform the OP, I should just let them bumble along when they could run into an issue in the future, when a comment here could save them time an energy, instead I should just answer their question and continue to let them move forward... I see. Makes total sense.... I think. And my suggested code doesn't take care of that or anything either, just pointing out that this is the scenario in-case the OP runs into an order of operations issue later.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('#example').dataTable(options)
     .$('td[class!="readonly"]')
     .makeEditable(options);
```

into this:

```
$('#example').dataTable(options)
     .$('td').not(".readonly")
     .makeEditable(options);
```